# How to keep Properties in sync

Tags: c#, wpf, automapper, prism

Given following classes below, i am looking for the best way to keep the *Parameters* of `ExecuteQuery` class in sync with *Parameters* of `Query` class.

I am working in WPF project using two views and viewmodels, one view is to define the model `Query`, has a DataGrid bind to `Parameters`. The other view is to define the model `ExecuteQuery` which has ComboBox to select target `Query` object. Once it is selected, i want to copy the Parameters from Query to ExecuteQuery so that it gets synced and any collection and properties change can be tracked and reflected in ExecuteQuery accordingly.

```
public class NameParameter : Entity
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => SetProperty(ref _name, value);
    }
}

public class KeyValueParameter : ClientEntity
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => SetProperty(ref _name, value);
    }

    private string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set => SetProperty(ref _value, value);
    }
}

public class Query
{
    private ObservableCollection<NameParameter> _parameters = new ObservableCollection<NameParameter>();
    public IEnumerable<NameParameter> Parameters => _parameters.AsEnumerable();

    public void AddParameter()
    {
        _parameters.Add(new NameParameter());
    }
}

public class ExecuteQuery
{
    private Query _query;
    public Query Query
    {
        get => _query;
        set => SetProperty(ref _query, value);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<KeyValueParameter> _parameters = new ObservableCollection<KeyValueParameter>();
    public IEnumerable<KeyValueParameter> Parameters => _parameters.AsEnumerable();
}
```

So far i have used *Automapper* to map different types with following configuration but i am still unsure if it is the right way to address this problem.

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
    cfg.CreateMap<NameParameter, KeyValueParameter>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Value, o => o.Ignore());
});
```

I can achieve it with some effort, but asking this question here to know an expert solution to address such repeated problem with minimal code changes and identify any pattern that most people uses.

Comment: Is there any reason, you store the data twice ? Why ExecuteQuery.Parameters can not just return a transoformed _query.Paramters ?

Comment: Query is listing the named parameters which can be used by mulitple ExecuteQuery and it should have same parameters in the form of KeyValueParameter to store the additional value.

Comment: You can convert this, then ExcuteQuery.Parameters is accessed. I see no reason to store it. ExecuteQuery is not modifying it's copy, or is it ?

Comment: I will restrict modification to Name coming from Query, but eventually it should be maintaining this data separately to hold the value for each argument. Currently, I have a DataGrid in ExecuteQuery showing readonly Name column and editable Value column.

Comment: You have to make your observable collection accessible, you subscribe to _Query._Parameters.CollcetionChanged and you rebuild your copy if signaled. What's in question about this, you are not a beginner.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that there could be several ways to accomplish it but i am looking for an elegant approach or pattern used by experts in this situation because not just CollectionChanged but also PropertyChanged has to be tracked. I got your point of making observable collection accessible but then i will break the abstraction to disallow outside world to make modification to my collection directly. I hope this can explain the situation well.

Comment: No, everything is covered by CollectionChanged. Add/Remove/Edit items.
The handler looks like `_parameters = _query.Parameters.Select(x => new KeyValueParameter( x.whatever..))` This one liner has not enough elegance ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205490/discussion-between-furqan-safdar-and-holger).

Comment: Indeed elegant, but when i tried using this idea and changing the Name of NamedParameter in Query, the collection changed is not called.

Comment: You have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for your data objects.

Comment: I have posted an answer, hoping to see your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Holger for your comments. Finally, this is how i have achieved it with so much event wiring which seems kind of dirty. Not sure if there is any better and clean way of doing it.

My original intent of posting this question was to seek any proficient way of abstracting this logic away from my domain objects.

```
public class Query
{
    private ObservableCollection<NameParameter> _parameters = new ObservableCollection<NameParameter>();
    public IEnumerable<NameParameter> Parameters => _parameters.AsEnumerable();

    public void AddParameter()
    {
        _parameters.Add(new NameParameter());
    }

    public void SubscribeParametersCollectionChanges(NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler)
    {
        _parameters.CollectionChanged += handler;
    }
}

public class ExecuteQuery
{
    public ExecuteQuery()
    {
        PropertyChanged += ExecuteQuery_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void ExecuteQuery_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Query))
            OnQuerySelection();
    }

    private Query _query;
    public Query Query
    {
        get => _query;
        set => SetProperty(ref _query, value);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<KeyValueParameter> _parameters = new ObservableCollection<KeyValueParameter>();
    public IEnumerable<KeyValueParameter> Parameters => _parameters.AsEnumerable();

    private void OnQuerySelection()
    {
        // subscribe to NamedParameters collection changed events
        DataElement?.SubscribeParametersCollectionChanges(Parameters_CollectionChanged);
        // calling this method explicitly so that if there are already Parameters in Source, bring them right away
        Parameters_CollectionChanged(this, null);
    }

    private void Parameters_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // subscribe to each object property changed events in NamedParameters 
        foreach (var namedParameter in Query.Parameters)
            if (namedParameter is INotifyPropertyChanged npc)
                npc.PropertyChanged += Parameters_PropertyChanged;
        // copying parameters from source to target
        _parameters = new ObservableCollection<KeyValueParameter>(
            Query.Parameters.Select(x => new KeyValueParameter(x.Name)));
        // raising event to notify UI for this change
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Parameters));
    }

    private void Parameters_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Name))
        {
            var namedParameter = Query.Parameters.ToList();
            for (var i = 0; i < namedParameter.Count; i++)
                _parameters[i].Name = namedParameter[i].Name;
        }
    }
}
```